# Increase and decrease element width on window resize

Tags: javascript, css

Imagen a responsive layout with an content area which is centered in browser window.

[image: Example of my layout]

When ever the window gets minimized/maximized the content area should fit the remaining space to the left and right, so no free space is wasted on smaller screens.

In order to achieve that I've made a small javascript which would do the job, but it causes high amount of cpu.

Is there a way to enlarge or reduce the width of the content area dynamicly with pure css?

```
"use-strict";
(function(){
function init(){
    var foo = new bar(getView());

    function getView(){
        return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    }

    window.onresize = function(){
        foo(getView());
    }
}

function bar(i) {
    return function(y){
        if(y > i)
            console.log('max');

        if(y < i)
            console.log('min');

        i = y;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
})();
```

Comment: Look into media queries http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Good point, thanks. Does work in case, but its more or less adaptive, makes the layout a little bit jumpy. I am looking for a solution which decreases/increases width fluidly

Comment: Media queries doesn't make your layout jumpy, it just allows you to load different css based on the width of the browser. If you want to make it move more smoothly, you can add a transition with easing.

Answer (score 1):

Use min-width for content area.

`.content {
  min-width : 200px;
  width:60%;
}`

Comment: You should provide an explication on how your answer solve the problem. If you do so your answer will be up-voted more often.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 700px;
min-width: 50%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

source & explain: 
[How do you increase element width as you decrease the window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112037/how-do-you-increase-element-width-as-you-decrease-the-window-size)