# How do you increase element width as you decrease the window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm coding a website to fit both desktop and mobile, and of course the initial thought is to use a percentage width and then setup a mobile CSS stylesheet that changes the element width to 100% if the screen is under 700px.

The problem with that is the "clunk" that occurs when you cross the barrier.

So I thought, "Why not add a jQuery resize script that fluidly resizes the element to avoid the clunk?"

The problem was writing the equation.

I figured it out, but now I'm worried about how much processing power it's using up. I don't want this feature to lag the rest of the website.

Here's my jFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jp685suz/1/

...and the equation:

```
var windowW = $(window).innerWidth();
var rangeMax = 1000; //Change occurs between 700px and 1000px
var rangeMin = 700;
var rangeDiff = 1000-700;
var minWidth = 50;
var dynWidth = Math.round(((1-(((rangeDiff-(rangeMax-windowW))/rangeDiff)/(100/(100-minWidth))))*100)*10)/10;
```

Try resizing the window to see what I mean. It's not laggy now, but add in a few high res photos in a slideshow and other jQuery functions and it isn't perfect. Of course this isn't a huge issue because most people don't resize their window very often, but I like to show off.

Can my equation be simplified? Maybe there's something built-in to jQuery that does this exact thing?

Comment: Keep in mind that a user won't be constantly resizing their window. Also, I'm a little confused as to what you're asking - you seem to have a working solution that does what you need.. what's your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

- `100%` width when window is less than `700px` wide.
- `50%` width when window is more than `1000px` wide.

Then, you decided to reduce the percentage linearly between `700px` and `1000px`.

[image]

However, there is a problem: when the percentage is resolved, the used width becomes

[image]

As you can see, increasing the width of the window reduces the width of the section, producing a very weird effect.

Let me propose a different approach:

- `100%` width when window is less than `700px` wide.
- `100% = 700px` width when window is `700px` wide.
- `700px` width when window is between `700px` and `1400px` wide.
- `50% = 700px` width when window is `1400px` wide.
- `50%` width when window is more than `1400px` wide.

That is, use a constant width of `700px`, and clamp it with percentages:

```css
width: 700px;
min-width: 50%;
max-width: 100%;
```

```css
section {
  width: 700px;
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: olivedrab;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>This olive green box will be a reasonable size on a big monitor (50% of the screen), and will fill the screen (100%) if it gets smaller than 700px (i.e. mobile).</p>
  <p>The transition is smooth. Go ahead, try resizing the window and see how pretty!</p>
  <p>This is not as "clunky" as setting a CSS mobile screen profile, but uses jQuery which isn't always a good idea.</p>
</section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS transitions for the effect you're after.

```
transition: width 1s ease;
```

See your amended fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3wtfenk2/

No javascript used.